# PHP When and why do I need to call store_result()?

Tags: php, mysqli

In the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) I found

> You must call **mysqli_stmt_store_result()** for every query that
>   successfully produces a result set (SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN),
>   if and only if you want to buffer the complete result set by the
>   client, so that the subsequent mysqli_stmt_fetch() call returns
>   buffered data.

I do not understand this explanation at all. In particular, I have no idea what is meant with with *buffer the complete result set by the client*.

---

For example, if I wanted to get the amount of num_rows of a select query, I usually did this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age ='3' "));
echo $result->num_rows;
```

If I use now prepared statments, then

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE age = ?';
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', 3);
$stmt->execute();
// $stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
```

returns always 0, except if I uncomment `// $stmt->store_result();`. I though prepare+bind+execute should be the same as the old `query` command, but apparently its not. What is the store_result method doing? Why do I need it here?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: you have to check the numrows before the store_result();   try something like this  $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;   $stmt->store_result();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you have to call `store_result()` is because prepared statements in mysqli by default operate in unbuffered mode.

This is contrary to the information presented in [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php). You have to keep in mind that mysqli was developed as a shim rather than a proper DB library. MySQLi is full of bugs and suffers from a lot of bad decisions. One of them is unbuffered mode for prepared statements.

In fact you do not have to use `store_result()` at all. This function is not very useful, because you still need to bind the results to variables and fetch each row individually. A much better option is `get_result()`.

```
$age = 3;
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE age = ?';
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $age);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

This is 4 lines compared to `query()` method, but the end result is the same. `$result` contains an instance of `mysqli_result` class.

You could write your own wrapper for it to make your life simpler. Here is an example how you could turn it into a single line with a wrapper function.

```
function mysqli_prepared_query(mysqli $mysqli, string $sql, array $params): mysqli_result
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($params)), ...$params);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result();
}

$result =  mysqli_prepared_query($mysqli, 'SELECT ?,?', [1, 2]);
```

Of course the best solution would be to switch to PDO or use some kind of abstraction library, so that you do not have to deal with these confusing methods.